# Am I being too lazy in asking this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

**Prospective question:** How can I use LuaTeX to detect the position of a math symbol (unary vs. binary, after/before parantheses) in order to put a custom amount of spacing around it?

Essentially, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391885/how-to-redefine-infix-binary-relational-operator-spacing-so-that-precedence-c) along with [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392081/how-does-tex-figure-out-whether-a-should-be-typeset-as-unary-or-binary) showed the importance of writing something akin to your own parser to allow dynamic spacing (i.e. dynamic '\medmuskip') around operators. I found out that someone else asked a similar question a while back: [Using operator spacing to indicate precedence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121848/using-operator-spacing-to-indicate-precedence)

I'd like to figure out how to write such a parser, using LuaTeX.

**Suspected issue with the question:** it requires the answerer to do a lot of work/shows that I didn't do enough of my own research, because one could argue that I could probably figure out the answer if I spent enough time reading docs etc.? Am I just being too lazy?

Your thoughts?

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4778/10995) as a starting point, read the [LuaTeX docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf), and ask a question once you get stuck.  If you ask your literally as you proposed it, then yes, you are lazy.

Comment: Yes. In short, well, erm, yes.

Comment: Just ask the question about your current state, and continue to work on it. When you have done enough research, post an answer.

Comment: Makes sense to me!

Comment: It is possible to pirate the xint parser to achieve what you want, without LuaTeX, if you limit yourself to expressions xint currently understands. (it might be possible hijacking l3fp do, but I don't know its implementation). But you seem to be intent into parsing (say à la MathJaX) all that TeX can typeset in math mode am I understanding this correctly?